# How do I use Tkinter to create line-wrapped text that fills the width of the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

The `Label` widget doesn't line-wrap. The `Message` widget will line-wrap text, but forces it to be roughly square.  Here's an example:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("hello")

Message(root, text=48*'xxxxx ').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

Label(root, text='Name:').grid(row=1, column=0)
Entry(root, width=50).grid(row=1, column=1)
Button(root, text="?").grid(row=1, column=2)

Button(root, text="Left").grid(row=2, column=0)
Button(root, text="Center").grid(row=2, column=1)
Button(root, text="Right").grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

I know that I can use `aspect=700` to change the shape, but hard-coding numbers like that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`wraplength` is indeed the correct answer, but it's a fixed width. If you have a dynamically sized `Label` you will need to update `wraplength` as it is resized.
You can do this by binding the `<Configure>` event:

```
label = tk.Label(root, text="My long text")
label.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: label.config(wraplength=label.winfo_width()))
```

In some configurations I do get wrapping that is slightly off, i.e. the text runs slightly off the edge of the `Label` before wrapping. I haven't figured out whether that's due to the font, any margins/padding, or what is going on. I just worked around this by subtracting a fixed amount from `label.winfo_width()` before feeding it into `wraplength`.

Comment: This is a good solution but the implementation may lead to an infinite loop since if calls the view configure on the view configure event. You may want to wrap the label in a Frame superview and bind the event listening to this view instead.

Answer (score 57):

The Tkinter `Label` widget does wrap. It is just that the default setting is no wrapping. To get the text on one to wrap set the `wraplength` parameter, the units for this are screen units so try `wraplength=50` and adjust as necessary. You will also need to set `justify` to `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, or `CENTER`.

Comment: It's also possible to set a binding on the widget so that you can dynamically change the wrap length when the widget changes size.

Comment: @JimDenny, what do you mean by screen units? I am new to this.

Comment: Can u maybe post some code? I have no idea where to insert WRAPLENGTH so this answer is useless.

Comment: @Brendan Just add those arguments to the Label widget. See Uduak Akpan's answer for more details.

Answer (score 18):

```
welcomenote = Label(root, text="Your long text", font="helvetica 14", 
wraplength=300, justify="center")
welcomenote.pack()
```

Comment: To cite OP: "but hard-coding numbers like that is what I'm trying to avoid."

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
tk.Label(root, textvariable=text, wraplength=500).pack()
```

Here 500 is the amount of pixels before the characters are put to the next line.